Wireguard(tuntap) systemd oneshot timeout
Environment
This is a vps Ubuntu server 22.04.5. Wireguard use tuntap instead of kernel mod.
Script
/etc/wireguard/gw0.sh can start wireguard correctly if run from command line:
# cleanup
echo "$(date) - cleanup"
/usr/sbin/ip link del gw0 2>&1
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE 2>&1

# setup
echo "$(date) - setup"
#/usr/sbin/ip tuntap add dev gw0 mode tun
/usr/bin/wireguard gw0 2>&1
/usr/sbin/ip a add 10.0.0.1/24 dev gw0
/usr/bin/wg set gw0 listen-port 12345
/usr/bin/wg set gw0 private-key /etc/wireguard/gw0.key
# wg0
/usr/bin/wg set gw0 peer <wg0 key> allowed-ips 10.0.0.2/32
# wg1
/usr/bin/wg set gw0 peer <wg1 key> allowed-ips 10.0.0.3/32

# start
echo "$(date) - start"
/usr/sbin/ip link set gw0 up 2>&1
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE 2>&1

# end
echo "$(date) - end"

exit 0

Output:
# /etc/wireguard/gw0.sh
Thu Dec  5 10:03:32 EST 2024 - cleanup
Cannot find device "gw0"
Thu Dec  5 10:03:32 EST 2024 - setup
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                      │
│   Running wireguard-go is not required because this  │
│   kernel has first class support for WireGuard. For  │
│   information on installing the kernel module,       │
│   please visit:                                      │
│         https://www.wireguard.com/install/           │
│                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Thu Dec  5 10:03:32 EST 2024 - start
Thu Dec  5 10:03:33 EST 2024 - end

Systemd Service
/etc/systemd/system/gw0.service:
[Unit]
Description = Start Wireguard gw0
After = network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target
[Service]
Type = oneshot
ExecStart = /usr/bin/bash -c "/etc/wireguard/gw0.sh >> /tmp/gw0.log"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Starting the service will always result in time out error, and no wireguard process:
# systemctl start gw0.service
Job for gw0.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status gw0.service" and "journalctl -xeu gw0.service" for details.

# systemctl status gw0.service
× gw0.service - Start Wireguard gw0
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gw0.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2024-12-05 10:12:07 EST; 34s ago
    Process: 95515 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c /etc/wireguard/gw0.sh >> /tmp/gw0.log (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 95515 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 05 10:10:37 mybox systemd[1]: Starting Start Wireguard gw0...
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: gw0.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: gw0.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: Failed to start Start Wireguard gw0.

# journalctl -xeu gw0.service
Dec 05 10:10:37 mybox systemd[1]: Starting Start Wireguard gw0...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gw0.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit gw0.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2611.
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: gw0.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: gw0.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit gw0.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'.
Dec 05 10:12:07 mybox systemd[1]: Failed to start Start Wireguard gw0.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gw0.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit gw0.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2611 and the job result is failed.

However, /tmp/gw0.log shows the script completed:
Thu Dec  5 10:10:37 EST 2024 - cleanup
Thu Dec  5 10:10:37 EST 2024 - setup
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                      │
│   Running wireguard-go is not required because this  │
│   kernel has first class support for WireGuard. For  │
│   information on installing the kernel module,       │
│   please visit:                                      │
│         https://www.wireguard.com/install/           │
│                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Thu Dec  5 10:10:37 EST 2024 - start
Thu Dec  5 10:10:37 EST 2024 - end

Question
Anyone has clue how to make gw0.service work?

Don't make it a Type=oneshot service.
The purpose of Type=oneshot services is to run short tasks, where 100% of the task is done in the "starting" phase and no processes (no daemons or anything else) remain afterwards. Such services will only be considered "started" when their main process exits, i.e. when it has completed its job.
For example, wg-quick or wg setconf (when using the kernel module) or iptables -A would use Type=oneshot because they only configure some kernel feature and exit, leaving no processes behind.
But because you're using "tuntap", you do have a persistent daemon process – the wireguard-go daemon needs to remain running the whole time – so Type=oneshot is not suitable because it would deliberately wait forever for the daemon to exit.
For wireguard-go, use one of the other types, such as Type=forking (probably the closest to how your script behaves) or notify (if wireguard-go supports this type) or simple/exec.

You nailed it and it is working with Type=forking! Thank you!
